# Configuring Assimp

Tags: cmake, build, assimp

I want to build ASSIMP without SMD importer.

I use cmake.

I added in CMakeLists:add_definitions(ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_SMD_IMPORTER)

I entered this in command prompt:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"   CMakelists.txt  -S ./  -B ./BUILD_ASSIMP
```

Normaly  after disabling SMD it should be written "disabled importer formats:SMD "  but it's only written  "disabled importer formats:"

Here is a part of the entire log:

```
--Enabled importer formats: AMF 3DS AC ASE ASSBIN B3D BVH COLLADA DXF CSM HMP IRRMESH IRR LWO LWS MD2 MD3 MD5 MDC MDL NFF NDO OFF OBJ OGRE OPENGEX PLY MS3D COB BLEND IFC XGL FBX Q3D Q3BSP RAW SIB SMD STL TERRAGEN 3D X X3D GLTF 3MF MMD STEP
-- Disabled importer formats:
-- Enabled exporter formats: 3DS ASSBIN ASSXML COLLADA OBJ OPENGEX PLY FBX STL X X3D GLTF 3MF ASSJSON STEP
-- Disabled exporter formats:
-- Configuring done
```

How to disable the SMD loader?

Comment: It simply tells you there are options on your command line that are not referenced in your CMakeLists.txt files. When checking current assimp I did not found the `ASSIMP_BUILD_SMD_LOADER` option. BTW the CMakelists.txt option is not needed, too. A command that succeeds without warning would look like this: `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DASSIMP_BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS=OFF -S ./  -B ./BUILD_ASSIMP`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the SMD_LOADER you need to specify which loaders shall be included:

```
cmake CMakeLists.txt -DASSIMP_BUILD_SMD_IMPORTER=ON
```

Now only the SMD loader will be included and all others will be disabled. Do this with the loaders you want to have and do not enable the SMD-Importer.

Or you can just add the following option in your CMakeLists-file which runs the assimp-build:

```
add_definition(ASSIMP_BUILD_NO_SMD_IMPORTER
```